# how to loop data from database separated with comma in php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a variable called `$to`. I want this variable to contain data separated by a comma like below:

```
$to='belong@gmail.com, getthis@gmail.com';
```

If there is only one email there will no comma; if there are multiple emails there will not be a comma after the last email.

Comment: You can use group_concat if you like to concatenate column values in mysql.

Comment: A PHP solution would be the use of `implode(',', $emails)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `explode` to convert it into array. Then you can traverse from array

```
<?php
 $to='belong@gmail.com, getthis@gmail.com';
 $to_array = explode(",", $to);
 foreach ($to_array as $key => $value) {
   echo $value;
 }
```

If you want to do opposite you can use `implode`

```
$to_array = array('belong@gmail.com', 'getthis@gmail.com');
$to = implode(",",$to_array);
echo $to;
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP asks for. The goal is to get the string with the values, not to split them.

Comment: @TobiasF. read question heading. OP asked for `how to loop data from database seperated with coma in php` which I have explain. BTW I have edited both

Answer (score 2):

```
try 
    $result = implode(',',$to);
```

Answer (score 2):

use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

for example:

```
$emails = ["a@email.com","b@email.com","c@email.com"];

$to = implode(',',$a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save all your eMails address in an array and then you can implode it with comma, it automatically handle all the cases

```
$addresses= array()
$addresses[] = 'belon@gmail.com';
$addresses[] = 'getthis@gmail.com';
$to = implode(",",$addresses);
```

You will find in $to all your addresses separated by comma except the last one